# What is the fastest method of sorting out duplicate strings

Tags: string, vb.net, duplicates

I am developing an app that focuses around manipulating strings in various ways. One of which is removing any duplicate items while combining files. 
I have attempted to use this:

```
Private Sub run()
    For Each filePath As String In ListBox1.Items
        For Each Line In IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
            Dim founds() As String = Line.Split(":")
            Dim hash As String = founds(0)
            Dim word As String = founds(1)
            foundList.Add(word)
            Dim result As List(Of String) = foundList.Distinct().ToList
            Label1.Text = result.Count
            For Each addstring In result
                ListBox2.Items.Add(addstring)
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Distinct was very slow in this fashion, so I tried using:

```
Private Sub run()
    For Each filePath As String In ListBox1.Items
        For Each Line In IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
            Dim founds() As String = Line.Split(":")
            Dim hash As String = founds(0)
            Dim word As String = founds(1)

            If Not foundList.Contains(word) Then
                foundList.Add(word)
                Label1.Text = foundList.Count
            End If
        Next
    Next
    For Each found In foundList
        ListBox2.Items.Add(found)
    Next
End Sub
```

This was much faster however still performs slower than what should be possible without using OpenCL or similar. I can write in C# if there is anything different available but this in .NET. 
Can anyone suggest a faster or more effective method? 
This can't possibly be it, surely I am missing something.

Comment: `Distinct()` was slow because you were calling it for every line in every file.  Instead, build up your `foundList` then call `Distinct()` on it.  In the same vein, you are populating your listbox on each line of each file.  Which as you can imagine is terrible for performance.  Only populate the list once.. after you have your distinct list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fabio got to the obvious answer before I finished this.  I've put some more detail in, but skip to the bottom for another idea.

---

The obvious speed issue is in the string comparison:

```
If Not foundList.Contains(word) Then
```

Comparing strings is a fairly expensive operation, and here you're comparing strings against a successively larger list of other strings.  For a short list that might be OK, but when you're dealing with big lists it's going slow down somewhat.

The better option is to hash each string once then compare the hashes.  There's some finesse required to handle [hash collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution), but when the bulk of the data is unique and the hash function is good then you'll get a huge improvement in the speed.

In .NET the [`HashSet(Of T)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) class implements hash-based storage and lookup.

Being a Set, `HashSet` will only hold one of any particular value, which handles the duplication issue.  It makes no guarantees about retaining the order of its contents, but in practice if you are adding only and never removing items then order is preserved.

Lookups in `HashSet` are very fast due to the way the hash values are stored and indexed internally.  Testing to see if a value exists in the set is *almost* unaffected by the number of items in the list.  I get lookup times on the order of ~50ns for lookups in lists from 1,000 to 1,000,000 strings with a simple test (100,000,000 lookups).

For your purposes the usage would be something like (in C#):

```
Private Sub Run()
    ' shortcut the file reads...
    Dim items = ListBox1.Items.OfType(Of String)()
        .SelectMany(Function(fn) File.ReadAllLines(fn))
        .Select(Function(i) i.Split(":"c)(1))
    Dim hash = New HashSet(Of String)(items)
    ListBox2.Items.Clear()
    ListBox2.Items.AddRange(hash.ToArray())
End Sub
```

(Sorry, VB is not my native language.)

---

Question is, will this actually speed things up?  You'll need to do some testing of your own, but I suspect that the answer *might* be: not much.

Yes, it's faster than using `Distinct` and `ToArray` to get an array of sorted values.  Almost twice as fast by my simple test.  ~180ms vs ~275ms for a million distinct 36-character strings (yes, they're Guids) in an array.  Not much of an increase.  YMMV, but if the operation is taking significantly more time than that then the `Distinct` is probably not your biggest problem.

Do some profiling and find the actual pain point.  I suspect that you'll find that `ListBox2` has the `Sorted` flag set.  Try this (again in C#, sorry):

```
Private Sub Run()
{
    Dim items = ListBox1.Items.OfType(Of String)().
        SelectMany(Function(fn) File.ReadAllLines(fn)).
        Select(Function(i) i.Split(":"c)(1))
    Dim hash = HashSet<string>(items)
    ListBox2.Items.Clear()
    Dim sorted = ListBox2.Sorted
    ListBox2.Sorted = false
    ListBox2.Items.AddRange(hash.ToArray())
    ListBox2.Sorted = sorted
}
```

If that's a lot faster then the problem isn't in the `Distinct` it's in the sort-on-insert which is painfully slow and almost always the *worst* option for sorted lists.

If it's not then the problem might be

Comment: Wow this a very detailed explanation. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer. I upvoted your answer and will choose in the morning after further testing. Thank you again for the explanation.

Comment: To convert to VB, change `private void` to `Private Sub`, remove the opening brace, change the closing brace to `End Sub`, change `var` to `Dim`, change `<string>` to `(Of String)`, change `<var> =>` to `Function(<var>)`, change `':'` to `":"c`, change `[1]` to `(1)`, and remove the semicolon at the end of each line.  It's possible that you need an underscore character to indicate continuation in the declaration of `items`, but probably not, VB has gotten very good at figuring out when a line is a continuation and when it's a new line.

Comment: I determined your answer to be the best for many reasons but mainly because of how descriptive you were. HashSet is the fastest method that I can tell available stock in .net. If appropriate I will gladly post a final bit of code for reference but your answer kind sir was supreme.

Answer (score 1):

Use `HashSet(Of String)`

```
Dim lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
Dim uniqueLines = New HashSet(Of String)(values)
```

After initialization `HashSet` will contains unique values.
You can use `HashSet(Of T).Add(value)` method - which return `true` if value was added to the set and `false` if value already exists in the set

```
Dim isAdded As Boolean = uniqueLines.Add("someValue")
If isAdded Then
    ' Do something if added
Else
    ' Do something if already exists
End if
```

`HashSet` have method `Contains` which algorithm is O(1) - use fixed amount of operations, where for example `List.Contains` method will iterate whole list until find given value (O(N) - amount of operation is equal amount of items in worth case)

So your function can be re-written as below

```
Private Sub run()
    ' get data
    Dim allItems = ListBox1.Items.
                            SelectMany(Function(path) IO.File.ReadAllLines(path)).
                            SelectMany(Function(line) Line.Split(":"))
    Dim uniqueItems = New HashSet(Of String)(allItems)

    ' update controls
    Label1.Text = uniqueItems.Count.ToString()
    ListBox2.Items.AddRange(uniqueItems.ToArray())
End Sub
```

Notice that items added to the `ListBox2` by using `.AddRange` method. This method will add items in one operation and re-draw control only one time. Where when you adding items one by one (using `.Add` method) you control re-drawing itself for every added item, which can be "heavy" for big amount of items.

Comment: This seems simple enough however still new to me. Im having issues applying this to my form.

Comment: @King96, can you describe issues you facing with this approach?

Comment: I am not sure how to integrate yours with what I have. I receive errors all over when I try. Reading more into hashSet now though. Will try again soon. Thank you none the less. There was nothing useful out for this particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

Get all values before using `Distinct` and adding them (the slowest part is still updating the control):

```
ListBox2.DataSource = (From line In IO.File.ReadLines(filePath) 
                       Select line.Split(":"c)(1) Distinct).ToList
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer because while it may not be the fastest method, your's was still more efficient than mine. Thank you for your input.